# Angular Chart JS - Multiple data sets with combined x axis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I would like to display two data sets. The x values of both are datetimes in a certain range but are not identical and may not even have the same number of points. How can I plot both data sets on the same chart showing only one x axis.

I did not have trouble showing one data set. The only examples I can find showing two data sets are sharing the same x axis values which is not the case for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it for me

```
data: [
  [ {x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 1, y: 3} ],
  [ {x: 0, y: 3}, {x: 2, y: 4} ]
]
```